# Variable not passing in POST method to same page

Tags: php, html

It seems that variables are not being passed to same page using POST method... I'm a beginner in html,php...
Please help...
table-name = member
attribute = name

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_POST{'name'};

$query = "INSERT INTO member (`name`) VALUES ('$name')";
mysqli_query($conn, $query);
header('Location: register.php');
}
?>

<form class="form-horizontal" action="register.php" method="post" id="input">
<div class="form-group">
  <label  class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="" />
    </div>
</div><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" form="input" class="btn btn-primary" value="Register" />
</form>
```

Comment: For a start, $_POST{'name'} should be $_POST['name'] with square brackets

Comment: $_POST{'name'} works fine... i have used this previously and it has worked.... anyway i changed it to $_POST['name'].. but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @Vishu Consistency is always a good start to keep coding readable. Admittedly I got to that, and didn't look further...

Comment: remove action action attribute value from form element.. so your form element will be...
<form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post" id="input">

Comment: @markdwhite Thank you for ur suggestion... I  didn't mean to offend u in any way... i'm just frustrated with my code... My real code is a lengthy one...actually a website... to make it easy for questioning i made a small code similar to mine... wen i tried this one though it seems to work... but not my real code.

Answer (score 1):

First of all try by change third line

```
$name = $_POST{'name'};
```

to

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
```

Because in post we need to use square braces... 
and if you are posting to same page then empty action attribute value, bcz empty action attribute means form will post to same page...
so form element will be as below...

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post" id="input">
```

Let me know if it help or not...

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
/* $_POST is super global array you can check weather you are getting data from post or not by using below line of code  and use square brakets for array
instead of { } */

echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
include 'connection.php';
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];

$query = "INSERT INTO member (`name`) VALUES ('$name')";
mysqli_query($conn, $query);
header('Location: register.php');
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="register.php" class="form-horizontal" id="input" method=
    "post" name="input">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input class="form-control" name="name" type="text" value="">
            </div>
        </div><br>
        <input class="btn btn-primary" form="input" name="submit" type="submit"
        value="Register">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
```

to

```
if(isset($_POST['name']))
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this :

`$name = $_POST{'name'};` to `$name = $_POST['name'];`
and

Remove form action : `action="register.php"`  to `action=""`

Answer (score 0):

use this code instead of your code..

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post" id="input">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label  class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="" />
        </div>
    </div><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Register" />
    </form>
```

Replace This Code With Your Existing Code

Answer (score 0):

If your HTML code and PHP code both on same page then set form `action=''`

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post" id="input">
```

Always check **mysqli_error()** and **mysqli_connect_errno()** in your query code.

also use **exit;** after `header("Location: YOUR_URL");`

Your PHP code should be as below:-

```
include 'connection.php';
if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {
  // You have wrongly used bracket. Use [] bracket instead of {}
  $name = $_POST['name'];

  /* check connection */
  if ( mysqli_connect_errno() ) {
    printf( "Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error() );
    exit();
  }

  $query = "INSERT INTO member(`name`) VALUES('$name')";
  // Check your query successfully executed or not
  $result = mysqli_query( $conn, $query ) or die( mysqli_error( $conn ) );

  header( 'Location: register.php' ); /* Redirect browser */
  exit;  // Write exit after header
  /* Make sure that code below does not get executed when redirect. */
}
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: @VishnuPrasad.R: You are welcome :) Is your problem resolved?

Comment: Welcome :) Please accept useful answer. So future visitor can find it as useful.

Comment: If you have any difficulty, refer this link:- http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';
if(isset($_POST['name'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];

$query = "INSERT INTO member(name) VALUES ('".$name."')";
mysqli_query($conn, $query);
}
?>

<form class="form-horizontal" action="register.php" method="post" id="input">
<div class="form-group">
  <label  class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="" />
    </div>
</div><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" form="input" class="btn btn-primary" value="Register" />
</form>
```

Also,
Please confirm $conn is not false